# Is it possible to enlarge a Core Plot graph, and have it respond to touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm new to the Core Plot framework and am looking at using in an iPad app.

- Is it possible to display a magnifier in the graph to enlarge just a small part of the graph?
- Can I display markers in a graph that respond to a click/touch?  Is the solution adding custom buttons programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot does not provide a magnifier. You'll have to implement that yourself.

What sort of marker do you want to display? What plot type?

You can set a plot delegate that will be notified when a data point is touched. How you respond is up to you. You can add a crosshair overlay, add a data label, change the plot symbol (on a scatter plot), or lots of other options. The example apps included with Core Plot demonstrate some of the possibilities.